# What is the exact difference between ?. and ?: operators in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not thinking about ?:(ternary operator). Sometimes I am watching in YouTube tutorials where people are using **?.** Operator in HTML pages, and sometimes they are using **?:** in TS(typescript) pages. I am not so clear how exactly they are different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So there is a difference when using the ? within Angular, here are the three ways you may be referring to for the usage.

**safe-operators**

When you set a value within the HTML with a question mark in it, this is a safe check, so you check the variable is defined before you access it. (trying at access values that do not exist will result in errors).

The snippet below would check `this.example` has a value before checking for text which would result in an error. If text is accessed while undefined this can almost assure unwanted behavior.

```
<p>{{example?.text}}</p>
```

This keeps everything safe, to read more about safe operators, have a read through the Angular docs [found here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

**Optional Parameters**

The next use, which is what I think you were looking for, is optional values in functions / interface. This means that the interface will not throw an error, if it is called without the `exampleValue` as it has now been defined as optional.

```
export interface Itest
{
 exampleValue?: string; // optional
 neededValue: string; // non-optional
}
```

Or within a function, without the optional indicator (`?`)  an error would occur if the function was called like. `this.exampleFunction();`

```
public exampleFunction(test?): void 
{
  console.log(test);
  // this function can be called with or without test being passed in without causing an error.
}
```

More examples of this can be found in this short article about [Optional Parameters](http://dotnetpattern.com/typescript-optional-parameters)

**Conditional (ternary) operator**

The question was not looking for this but thought it would make sense to pop it in as its another case where the `?` can be seen in use.

When seen in typescript you can use it in a conditional ternary statement `(if / else)` looking like so.

```js
const example = 'hello';
console.log(example === 'hello' ? 'im true' : 'im false');
```

which would be the same as writing the following statement.

```js
    const example = "hello";
    
    if (example === 'hello')
    {
      console.log('im true');
    }else 
    {
      console.log('im false');
    }
```

More information and uses of the Conditional (ternary) operator can be found [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Ugh, don't use `console.log` (or anything with side-effects) inside a ternary expression!

Comment: Was just to highlight quite easily in an example, what would you suggest for an easy to understand example?

Comment: Thank you @dince12, But n typescript I am not talking about ternary operator, which I already mentioned in question title.

Comment: `console.log(example === 'hello' ? 'im true' : 'im false';`

Comment: Sorry miss read, added to answer the use you were looking for :- )

Comment: @RajeshkumarGone to be precise it's called safe navigation operator or Elvis operator using which you safely access property values . It's most useful in accessing value of `errors` property in a formcontrol of reactive form. The part after `?.` will only be evaluated if the previous part was not null else it does not throw any exception.

Comment: Typescript does not have support of 'safe navigation operator' yet https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16. Safe navigation is angular feature https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 2):

`?.` is a [safe-navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator). It simply makes it so no errors will be thrown if the preceding value is null. There are some nitty-gritty details at play, but it can basically be thought of as a null-checking ternary expression.

```
<div>{{item?.value}}</div>
```

... is roughly the same as:

```
<div>{{item ? item.value : null}}</div>
```