# Understanding question mark, colon and undefined in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax

I'm new to angular and typescript and trying to understand what exactly is happening in this method:

```
    updatePostcode() {
    this.FilterService.updatePostcode({

      postcode: this.regionFormGroup.get('hasPostcode').value ? 
      this.regionFormGroup.get('postcode').value : undefined

    })

    this.regionFormGroup.get('postcode').reset()
  }
```

Ok, it's a method to update the postcode.

- What does the question mark mean?
- "postcode" is set to `this.regionFormGroup.get('hasPostcode').value`?
- What does the colon and the `undefined` mean? ( `: undefined`)

The problem is that the form is getting resetted and the entered postcode by the user is getting replaced by nothing if the updatePostcode method is called.

Comment: I answered something similar a while back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815790/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-and-operators-in-angular/54815879#54815879

Answer (score 6):

```
this.regionFormGroup.get('hasPostcode').value ? this.regionFormGroup.get('postcode').value : undefined
```

This is a conditional (ternary) operator. Before question mark it is condition(`this.regionFormGroup.get('hasPostcode').value`) if that condition is true then the value after question mark is picked `this.regionFormGroup.get('postcode').value` otherwise `undefined`

You can read more about ternary operator by following below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

Question mark is a **ternary** in JavaScript.

It replaces an `if/else` statement.

```
if (this.regionFormGroup.get('hasPostcode').value) {
  postcode = this.regionFormGroup.get('postcode').value
} else {
  postcode = undefined
}
```

In your case, this is faster to use ternary operator rather than defining variable value in an if/else statement.

`condition ? if then : else then;`

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)